# Passing only few data to the JSON.parse() into Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, elasticsearch

Here I only have to allow few data coming from JSON and index in Elasticsearch. So what is the perfect way to do it, rather than delete each separately?

```
var elasticData= JSON.parse(result.body);
        elasticData = elasticData.res;
        elasticData["id"] = elasticData._id;
        delete elasticData["__v"];
        delete elasticData["_id"];
        delete elasticData["addressee"];
        delete elasticData["abbreviation"];
        delete elasticData["care_of"];
        delete elasticData["address_1"];
        delete elasticData["address_2"];
        delete elasticData["company_id_legacy"];        
        elasticSearch_common.createCompanyIndex(elasticData);
```

For Example: I only have to pass `("name","id","address")` and rest of them I don't want to pass it. But there's lots of other data(s) are available in same JSON.

```
{
    "userId":"34234234234gjgjg894734g",
  "company":{ 
  "id" : "21", 
  "addressee" : {
      "addressee" : "EXAMPLE", 
      "title_name" : "", 
      "salutation" : "Dear:", 
      "comments" : "", 
      "email" : "one@one.com", 
      "phone" : "", 
      "fax" : "", 
      "extention_group" : "", 
      "ext" : ""
  }, 
  "abbreviation" : "", 
  "care_of" : "", 
  "address_1" : "2", 
  "address_2" : "", 
  "address_3" : "", 
  "state" : "CA", 
  "zip" : "90024", 
  "is_deleted" : false, 
  "company_code" : "sdas", 
  "parent_company" : null, 
  "name" : "NIOE", 
  "createdBy" : "Dat", 
  "modifiedBy" : "Dat", 
  "createdDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
  "modifiedDate" : "2019-08-22T19:10:50.000+0000", 
}
```

This is the actual JSON, And I want below as the elasticsearch index data to be pushed.

```
{ name: 'NIOE',
  id: '21' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about whitelisting?

```
// raw data you get from wherever
const elasticData = JSON.parse(result.body);

// object to index into ES
const toIndex = {};

// whitelist of fields to index
["name", "id", "address"].forEach(field => {
  toIndex[field] = elasticData.company ? elasticData.company[field] : null;
});

// assert: toIndex now contains only the fields you want to index
elasticSearch_common.createCompanyIndex(toIndex);
```

Comment: still getting the whole data

Comment: Very doubtful... can you update your question with the actual code you now have?

Comment: Updated, but not major change, added JSON

Comment: The problem is that everything is nested under the `company` field. so simply replace `elasticData[field];` by `elasticData.company[field];`

Comment: `var elasticData= JSON.parse(result.body);
        elasticData = elasticData.res;
        elasticData["id"] = elasticData._id;
        const toIndex = {};

        ["name", "id","address"].forEach(field => {
        toIndex[field] = elasticData.company[field];
        });
        console.log(elasticData);   
        elasticSearch_common.createCompanyIndex(elasticData);`

Comment: That means some of your data doesn't have the `company` field with all the details... you need to protect your code against that... this is not an ES question anymore.. it's basic JavaScript coding.

Comment: So what would be the solution for this?

Comment: My code above is basic but it works provided all your documents contain a `company` field. You need to protect your code against edge cases. See my updated version and try again.

Comment: `const toIndex = {};

        // whitelist of fields to index
        ["name", "id", "address"].forEach(field => {
            toIndex[field] = elasticData.company ? elasticData.company[field] : null;
          });
          console.log(toIndex);
          // assert: toIndex now contains only the fields you want to index
          elasticSearch_common.createCompanyIndex(toIndex);`

Using this code

Comment: I get `{ name: 'NIOE', id: '21', address: undefined }`, so you must be doing something wrong

Comment: `var elasticData= JSON.parse(result.body);
        elasticData = elasticData.res;
        elasticData["id"] = elasticData._id;
        const toIndex = {};

        // whitelist of fields to index
        ["name", "id", "address"].forEach(field => {
            toIndex[field] = elasticData.company ? elasticData.company[field] : null;
          });
          console.log(toIndex);
          // assert: toIndex now contains only the fields you want to index
          elasticSearch_common.createCompanyIndex(toIndex);`

My Full Code

Comment: How does `result.body` look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113336/elasticsearch-update-is-not-getting-reflect-on-elasticsearch-index

Can you help me with this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163731/deleting-an-id-from-elasticsearch-index